# Magento setup on AWS

Tags: database, magento, amazon-web-services, database-versioning

We had a On Prem Setup for Magento and it was working fine however we migrated it to AWS environment and our site performance is gone down very drastically especially the DB sever. Is there any To DO or check list that we can run and find out route cause.

Comment: Can you provide a rough outline of] what services you'r running and your sizes? (ie 2 x ec2 t2.med + ELB + RDS m4.lg) There are lots of configs possible given AWS services and sizes and with a slight bit of extra info it would be easier to more specifically answer your question.

I'm running several Magento production workloads on AWS, each with a different profile.  In general you can probably get better price / performance of Magento on physical hardware until you start trying to add fault-tolerance and high-availability with global user base, but we're AWS fans and can help with more detail

Comment: Agree with BJ, need more details. Also agree on the fact that a dedicated server is generally better than a virtual one, for many reasons, one of which is that the (remote) database server adds latency to your requests.
Personally, I would suggest UKFast for a dedicated Magento server: they rock and provide specific support and optimisation for Magento. You may not need to even think about scaling, once you've got one of their servers!